# What are the drawbacks of use webpack-dev-server as a backend in development?

Tags: express, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

The [official documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) says:

> The webpack-dev-server is a little node.js Express server, which uses the webpack-dev-middleware to serve a webpack bundle.

I can without much trouble use this already created server to serve my API backend in development and indeed some boilerplates use this kind of approach.

But then the [docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#combining-with-an-existing-server) says:

> You may want to run a backend server or a mock of it in development. You should not use the webpack-dev-server as a backend. Its only purpose is to serve static (webpacked) assets.

Why is that ?
Why i can't use webpack-dev-server as a backend **only** in development ?
Is there any particular reason for that ?

For context, im doing React development with an Express backend for the API.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "back end" means things like API endpoints and dynamic processing. As you yourself mentioned:

> Its only purpose is to serve static (webpacked) assets.

This means it can't do things like talk to a data store or other dynamic processing, which you may need for your app. If all you are doing is developing front end components that don't need to talk to an API (ie: a "back end") then `webpack-dev-server` is more than adequate.

Note there are other solutions, like using `webpack-dev-server` to serve your static html/css/js files, and having a *separate* back end running on another port. This is perfectly valid, but many find it inconvenient to have to specify absolute URLs, as you would have to prefix every API call with `localhost:[port]/endpoint` instead of just `/endpoint`.

*EDIT*

There's no *technical* reason you *can't* do that. The only answer to your actual question of "what are the drawbacks" that I can give would be: it's not the intended use, and the author will most likely not support or offer assistance if used in another way.

Ultimately, it's all JS and you can pretty much do what you want.

Comment: "I can without much trouble use this already created server to serve my API backend". "it can't do things like talk to a data store or other dynamic processing" --- it's simply an express server, you surely can add more handlers for your api.

Comment: @rossipedia Look at [this](https://github.com/mjackson/web-starter/blob/master/modules/server/index.js#L56) boilerplate. In dev mode he created a `webpack-dev-server` to talk to backend API too (See the router where you can do dynamic processing)

Comment: Okay maybe "can't" should be replaced with "shouldn't". You can pretty much do whatever you want in JS, but my point is that the intended use for `webpack-dev-server` is specifically for serving files that webpack produces, not be the basis of your back end

Comment: That boilerplate looks pretty neat, although I _personally_ would integrate `webpack-dev-middleware` with `webpack-hot-middleware` instead. But that's my own personal preference.

Comment: "Okay maybe "can't" should be replaced with "shouldn't"." --- and that's the whole point of the question. It's: what is the *technical* reason to avoid that. We all may like something and may not like something else, but as *engineers* we must be driven by rational reasons. Your answer does not reveal any of those.

Comment: The question itself is flawed then. The quoted statement says "should not", and then OP goes on to ask "why can't I?". There's no way to sufficiently answer a question like that in the way you mean (from what I understand).